# Sending ACE editor changes as a single string to mongodb via socket.io

Tags: node.js, mongodb, sockets, socket.io, ace-editor

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">
<title>Editor</title>
<style type="text/css" media="screen">
body {
    overflow: hidden;
}

#editor {
    margin: 0;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<script src="http://127.0.0.1:8080/socket.io/socket.io.js"> </script>
<script>
(function(){
  var getNode = function(s){
    return document.querySelector(s);
   },

  textarea = getNode('.code editor');

  try{
   var socket = io.connect('http://127.0.0.1:8080');
  } catch(e){

  }

  if(socket !== undefined){



//put latest string in DB to ACE
socket.on('output', function(data){
  if(data.length){
    var x = data.length-1;
    editor.setValue(data[x].code);
  }
});


socket.on('code-changes', function(){
  editor.on("change", function(data){
    var code = editor.getValue();
    code = data;
    socket.emit('input',{
      code: data
    });
  });
});


/*
// after keydown put new string to DB
  editor.on('change', function(data){
    var code = editor.getValue();
      socket.emit('input',{
        code: code
      });
  });

 //if(asciiValue <=0 || asciiValue >= 255){
    socket.emit('input',{
      code: code
    });
    console.log("inserted");
 */
}

})();
</script>

<div id="aceEditor" style="height: 500px; width: 500px">some text</div>

 <script src="src-noconflict/ace.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"> </script>
 <script>
 var editor = ace.edit("aceEditor");
 var code = editor.getValue();

 //editor.setValue("new code here");
 editor.getSession().setValue(editor.getValue(), 1);
 editor.setTheme("ace/theme/twilight");
 editor.session.setMode("ace/mode/javascript");
 </script>

 </body>
 </html>
```

Server.js:

```
var mongo = require('mongodb').MongoClient;
var app = require('express')();
var http = require('http').Server(app);
var client = require('socket.io')(http);//.listen(8080).sockets;

app.get('/', function(req, res){
    res.sendFile(__dirname + '/static' + '/index.html');
});

mongo.connect('mongodb://127.0.0.1/code', function(err, db){
    if(err) throw err;

    client.on('connection', function(socket){

    var col = db.collection('messages');

    col.find().limit(3).sort({_id: 1}).toArray(function(err, res){
        if(err) throw err;
        socket.emit('output',res);
    });

    socket.on('input', function(data){
        var code = data.code;

        client.emit('output', [data]);
        console.log(data);
        col.insert({code: code}, function(){
            console.log("inserted");
        })
    });

});
});

http.listen(8080, function(){
    console.log('listening on 8080');
});
```

I having problems sending code from ace editor to mongodb via a socket.emit.
and I'm not why the code is not sending to mongo. I tried to emit the code with editor.getValue(); I'm not sure 100% how editor.on(change) works fully..... Any tips would be much appreciated.

Comment: Is this your complete code?

Answer (score 0):

I think you are doing wrong here:

```
//socket.on('code-changes', function(){ // Editor's changes should not be within socket event handling
  editor.on("change", function(data){
    var code = editor.getValue();
    code = data;
    socket.emit('input',{
      code: data
    });
  });
//});
```